# How to upgrade only the software (but not upgrade Ubuntu release) via shell?

Tags: updates

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Usually in Ubuntu Unity/Gnome, I use "Update Manager" and it may show that "14.04.4 LTS" is available and e.g. 673 updates could be updated.

And I only want to "Install Updates" of those 673 updates, and I do not want to upgrade to 14.04.4 LTS. Just keep on my 12.04 LTS is good for me.
All these are easily done via "Update Manager". But how to do it via ssh shell?

I don't want to connect my display and show the GUI desktop. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will not upgrade to 14.04 release and just install the required updates.