# How can I update KDE Plasma to 5.13 on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, 18.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma

I thought that upgrading to 18.04.1 would give me KDE Plasma 5.13, having read [this page](https://community.kde.org/Neon/BionicUpgrades), but thanks to the comments here I realised that I already have 18.04.1. I don't see any notification from the Updates widget about a newer version of Plasma though. Why is that? Can I get the latest version?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` must get the job done. Or you can use `update-manager -c`. You can verify your version with `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: For more information [click here](https://www.fosslinux.com/4022/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-released-here-is-how-to-upgrade-now.htm/).

Comment: Wow, it seems that I'm already on 18.04.1, thank you for the `lsb_release` hint. The issue I asked this question was the need to update KDE plasma to 5.13, I was wrong and thought it's included in 18.04.1. Sorry for the confusion and wrong question, but could you help me with this update: https://community.kde.org/Neon/BionicUpgrades (I need the same in CLI, I'm stuck on step 3 where it says you'll see a notification). I'll keep my original question untouched since your answer perfectly solves my question above, just adding an update in the body of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04 and KDE neon Bionic are two different things. The former is supported here, the latter isn't.

Comment: Yep, I unedrstood @DKBose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade only the software (but not upgrade Ubuntu release) via shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747151/how-to-upgrade-only-the-software-but-not-upgrade-ubuntu-release-via-shell)

Comment: @sharipov_ru, what you can do is to reword your question *and* its title to make clear what you intended as expressed by your comments. Basically, it's my understanding that you wanted to update KDE Plasma from 5.12 to 5.13 in Kubuntu 18.04 which is a totally legitimate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://community.kde.org/Neon/BionicUpgrades isn't meant for users of Kubuntu. It's meant for users of KDE neon which isn't supported at Ask Ubuntu.

If you're on Kubuntu 18.04, please note that Plasma 5.12 is regarded as LTS which means you'll get updates only to 5.12 and you won't get updated to Plasma 5.13 or higher during the life of Kubuntu 18.04.

Please monitor https://kubuntu.org/news/ or  https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/30-Kubuntu-Announcements for news on availability of Plasma updates for Kubuntu 18.04..

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer, that make sense to me. I'll be looking for upcoming updates and announcements, good to know about these announcements links.

Answer (score 1):

I see your question is pointless now, as you were already in 18.04.01. You might consider deleting it.

Or, for the record, in order for it to have its answer.

As said in a comment by @Kulfy:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can also use

update-manager -c

(if you have that installed)

You can verify your version with

```
lsb_release -a
```

But, as said in @DKBosse's answer, you will not get Plasma 5.13 in this way, only updates to 5.12.

(Testing 5.13 in Neon a few months ago it seemed unstable to me.)

Comment: This answer seem to sum up my comment and DK's answer. :-)

Comment: @Kulfy - Indeed. And it says so too: it even includes your comment above :-)

Comment: @Kulfy - In case you want to post your comment as answer I can delete my answer, in which my own contribution was mostly to suggest to the OP to delete this question altogether.

Comment: First of all for me, it doesn't matter whether you post or me. The main thing which matters is the answer, that should be correct and reliable. Secondly, I guess questions can't be deleted by the OP if it has been answered. So, there is no need to delete this answer. :-)

Comment: Yep, thanks for all explanations. I cannot delete the question unfortunately.

Comment: Despite the confusion I found useful information in DK Bose's answer; if this question is deleted so is that useful information.